# AutoHotKey - Listen to string after PrintScreen button is pressed?

Tags: string, paint, autohotkey, photoshop, printscreen

I want my script to listen to the string I will enter after the PrintScreen button is pressed. For example, if I press the PrintScreen button and type "paint" afterwards, it should open MSPaint. If I however type "photoshop", it should open Photoshop.. Is this possible?

Here is my attempt, a completely failure (I'm new to AHK by the way..)

```
~PrintScreen::paint::
    Run, MSPaint
    WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
    Send, ^v
return

~PrintScreen::photoshop::
    Run, Photoshop
    WinWaitActive, Adobe Photoshop CS6
    Send, ^v
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are right, `printScreen::paint::` is no valid AutoHotkey code.

Make use of Ahk's [Input](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm) command instead - it was made to listen for strings / characters:

```
~PrintScreen::
    input, outputString, i, {enter}.{esc}{tab}
    if outputstring = paint
    {
        Run, MSPaint
        WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
        Send, ^v
    } else if outputstring = photoshop
    {
        Run, Photoshop
        WinWaitActive, Adobe Photoshop CS6
        Send, ^v
    }
return
```

I however encourage you to have a look at input's options yourself to adjust it to your needs. Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much, I should've looked up the input command I guess :P